# passing array inside return function: jquery dataTable

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatable

I want this array item seperately to use in function to send and receive data from database. Here is what I tried.

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
                        {
                            "aTargets": [0],
                            "mRender": function(data, type, row) { 
                                var arr = data.split("~@~");
                                return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="jQuery(this).fill_request(\'' + arr[0] + "," + arr[2] + "," + arr[3] + '\');" title="' + arr[1] + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>';
                            }
                        }
                    ]
```

here is my function where I have to receive the parameters:

```
 jQuery.fn.fill_invoice_request = function(contract_invoice_request_id,contract_id, service_first_id) { 
    alert(contract_id);
    alert(service_first_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer where I seperated the arrays with the backslash and a comma in the **return** statement in jquery dataTable.

```
return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="jQuery(this).fill_invoice_request(\'' + arr[0] + '\', \'' + arr[2] + '\', \'' + arr[3] + '\');" title="' + arr[1] + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>';
```

I can seperate the array values using the  **('\')**  to pass them as the parameters to the function.